# Javascript off-DOM object events and event bubbling

Tags: javascript, events, composite, event-bubbling

Does anyone know of either a library or a pattern I can use to implement events and event bubbling in a javascript object graph without going through the DOM?

In short, I have an instance of a class that contains instances of other classes and I want to trigger events from the subclasses that can bubble up the graph/chain.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[bob.js framework](http://www.bobjs.com) exposes event mechanism that you can use. Either as an object of the event, or ask bob.js to create functions on your object. Here's the second approach as it's cleaner to read (see note about **bubbling** below):

```
var DataListener = function() { 
    var fire = bob.event.namedEvent(this, 'received'); 
    this.start = function(count) { 
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
            fire(i + 1); 
        } 
    }; 
}; 
var listener = new DataListener(); 
listener.add_received(function(data) { 
    console.log('data received: ' + data); 
}); 
listener.start(5); 
// Output: 
// data received: 1 
// data received: 2 
// data received: 3 
// data received: 4 
// data received: 5
```

As about **bubbling**: bob.js does not support bubbling (at the moment at least). Besides, ***bubbling would be possible if the events defined on the parent are similar to events defined on the child (it's the case with Html DOM elements, but not always so with off-DOM objects)***. However, as a workaround, you can have child event listener to fire an event on the parent object, - the effect will be something like bubbling.

Comment: I think the OP asked specifically about bubbling.

Comment: I mentioned the answer about bubbling as well, if you have noticed.

Comment: Yes, but that library doesn't support it… Of course you can mimic bubbling with every event/pubsub library by `child.addListener(parent.trigger)` :-)

Comment: I explained (now in bold) that bubbling is very specific and theoretically cannot exist off-dom or off-composites.

Comment: Sure, but the OP *has* an object graph (with composite pattern).

Comment: Basically, I answered the question: bubbling is impossible without custom code in any case unless the object (such as DOM element) supports bubbling up. It's not about event, it's about the event container object capabilities (any composite structure of pure JS objects does not support bubbling without custom code in the composite object). I hope now I made myself clear.